# How does "for<>" syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?

Tags: rust, syntax

Consider the following code:

```
trait Trait<T> {}

fn foo<'a>(_b: Box<dyn Trait<&'a usize>>) {}
fn bar(_b: Box<dyn for<'a> Trait<&'a usize>>) {}
```

Both functions `foo` and `bar` seem to accept a `Box<Trait<&'a usize>>`, although `foo` does it more concisely than `bar`.  What is the difference between them?

Additionally, in what situations would I need `for<>` syntax like that above?  I know the Rust standard library uses it internally (often related to closures), but why might my code need it?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`for<>` syntax is called *higher-ranked trait bound* (HRTB), and it was indeed introduced mostly because of closures.

In short, the difference between `foo` and `bar` is that in `foo()` the lifetime for the internal `usize` reference is provided *by the caller* of the function, while in `bar()` the same lifetime is provided *by the function itself*. And this distinction is very important for the implementation of `foo`/`bar`.

However, in this particular case, when `Trait` has no methods which use the type parameter, this distinction is pointless, so let's imagine that `Trait` looks like this:

```
trait Trait<T> {
    fn do_something(&self, value: T);
}
```

Remember, lifetime parameters are very similar to generic type parameters. When you use a generic function, you always specify all of its type parameters, providing concrete types, and the compiler monomorphizes the function. Same thing goes with lifetime parameters: when you call a function which have a lifetime parameter, *you* specify the lifetime, albeit implicitly:

```
// imaginary explicit syntax
// also assume that there is TraitImpl::new::<T>() -> TraitImpl<T>,
// and TraitImpl<T>: Trait<T>

'a: {
    foo::<'a>(Box::new(TraitImpl::new::<&'a usize>()));
}
```

And now there is a restriction on what `foo()` can do with this value, that is, with which arguments it may call `do_something()`. For example, this won't compile:

```
fn foo<'a>(b: Box<Trait<&'a usize>>) {
    let x: usize = 10;
    b.do_something(&x);
}
```

This won't compile because local variables have lifetimes which are strictly smaller than lifetimes specified by the lifetime parameters (I think it is clear why it is so), therefore you can't call `b.do_something(&x)` because it requires its argument to have lifetime `'a`, which is strictly greater than that of `x`.

However, you can do this with `bar`:

```
fn bar(b: Box<for<'a> Trait<&'a usize>>) {
    let x: usize = 10;
    b.do_something(&x);
}
```

This works because now `bar` can select the needed lifetime instead of the caller of `bar`.

This does matter when you use closures which accept references. For example, suppose you want to write a `filter()` method on `Option<T>`:

```
impl<T> Option<T> {
    fn filter<F>(self, f: F) -> Option<T> where F: FnOnce(&T) -> bool {
        match self {
            Some(value) => if f(&value) { Some(value) } else { None }
            None => None
        }
    }
}
```

The closure here must accept a reference to `T` because otherwise it would be impossible to return the value contained in the option (this is the same reasoning as with `filter()` on iterators).

But what lifetime should `&T` in `FnOnce(&T) -> bool` have? Remember, we don't specify lifetimes in function signatures only because there is lifetime elision in place; actually the compiler inserts a lifetime parameter for each reference inside a function signature. There *should* be *some* lifetime associated with `&T` in `FnOnce(&T) -> bool`. So, the most "obvious" way to expand the signature above would be this:

```
fn filter<'a, F>(self, f: F) -> Option<T> where F: FnOnce(&'a T) -> bool
```

However, this is not going to work. As in the example with `Trait` above, lifetime `'a` is *strictly longer* than the lifetime of any local variable in this function, including `value` inside the match statement. Therefore, it is not possible to apply `f` to `&value` because of lifetime mismatch. The above function written with such signature won't compile.

On the other hand, if we expand the signature of `filter()` like this (and this is actually how lifetime elision for closures works in Rust now):

```
fn filter<F>(self, f: F) -> Option<T> where F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a T) -> bool
```

then calling `f` with `&value` as an argument is perfectly valid: *we* can choose the lifetime now, so using the lifetime of a local variable is absolutely fine. And that's why HRTBs are important: you won't be able to express a lot of useful patterns without them.

You can also read another explanation of HRTBs in [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/hrtb.html).

Comment: Awesome! This is really clear, thanks. Hopefully this will be the canonical answer for this question. As a follow up (and if you have a link, that would be fine, as it's a little beyond the scope of my original question I think): why are they *higher rank* trait bounds? Do they have anything to do with higher-kinded types (which I am slightly familiar with)?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty yes, I believe they are called like that exactly after HKTs, because they do resemble them. I can imagine that HKTs could also be written with `for`, if they were available: `for<T> Monad<T>`, or at least, they have similar concepts - designating an infinite number of trait bounds (or types, in case of HKTs), parameterized with something (lifetimes or types). That said, it is conceivable for HRTBs to support types as well of lifetimes, it's just no one came up with a concrete design yet.

Comment: I think higher kinded types are orthogonal to higher rank types. Higher rank types describe where quantification can occur in a type signature and higher kinded types refer to writing polymorphic code over type constructors. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317768/kind-vs-rank-in-type-theory

Comment: @BurntSushi5 oh well, I always confuse them one for another :(

Comment: Is HRTB the Rust name for Haskell's `QuantifiedConstraints`?

Comment: @dspyz Yes, indeed :-)