# Lifetime subtyping and generics: "lifetime parameter not allowed" error

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

I tried to follow the [strategy described in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html#ensuring-one-lifetime-outlives-another-with-lifetime-subtyping) (and the compiler), but I'm stuck on the following error:

```
lifetime parameters are not allowed on this type: lifetime parameter not allowed
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
struct FooRef<'a, F: 'a>(&'a F);

struct Bar<'a, 'f: 'a, F: Foo<'f>> {
    filter: &'a FooRef<'f, F<'f>>,
}
```

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, What is `Foo`? Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Define a trait with a function that returns an associated type with the same lifetime as one parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42583027/155423).

Answer (score 2):

`F` is a type variable, not a type and as such cannot have type or lifetime parameters of its own. If you need to constrain a type variable to only hold references that are bounded by a lifetime, you can use the lifetime as a bound:

```
struct Bar<'a, 'f: 'a, F: Foo<'f> + 'f> {
    filter: &'a FooRef<'f, F>,
}
```