# Code working with elided lifetimes, not with explicit

Tags: rust

The following code works fine:

```
fn get<F: Fn(&[u8]) -> u8>(f: F) -> u8 {
    f(&[1, 2, 3])
}
```

However, when I add explicit lifetime information to it, it doesn't:

```
fn get<'inp, F: Fn(&'inp [u8]) -> u8>(f: F) -> u8 {
    f(&[1, 2, 3])
}
```

What lifetime does the compiler infer in the working code?

I'm using Rust 1.18.0.

The error message is:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> test.rs:4:8
  |
4 |     f(&[1, 2, 3])
  |        ^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
5 | }
  | - temporary value only lives until here
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'inp as defined on the body at 3:49...
 --> test.rs:3:50
  |
3 |   fn get<'inp, F: Fn(&'inp [u8]) -> u8>(f: F) -> u8 {
  |  __________________________________________________^
4 | |     f(&[1, 2, 3])
5 | | }
  | |_^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lifetimes in trait bounds are a bit special and the `Fn` family of traits has a special lifetime elision rule. We'll dive into that, but first, here it the correct explicitly annotated version:

```
fn get<F: for<'inp> Fn(&'inp [u8]) -> u8>(f: F) -> u8 {
    f(&[1, 2, 3])
}
```

Oh gosh, what is this `for<'inp>` doing there? It's a so called *higher ranked trait bound* (HRTB) and it's used here to make `'inp` universally quantiefied in regards to `f`. In order to fully understand that, we need to understand a bit of theory.

---

#### Who has the choice?

Let's take a look at an easy example:

```
fn bar<'a>(x: &'a u8) {}
```

Here, `bar()` is generic of the lifetime `'a`. The syntax above reads: "choose any `'a` and there is a `bar()` that will work with `'a`". This means that we can choose any `'a` we want, and `bar()` works! Who are "we"? "We" are the *caller* -- the one calling `bar`. This will be important later: the *caller* chooses the generic parameters. We can call `bar()` with a `&'static u8` as well as with a reference that doesn't live as long.

Now you might ask: are there situations where the *caller* doesn't choose the generic parameter, but someone else does? Yes, there are! Sadly, it's a bit more difficult to understand, because it doesn't occur too often in today's Rust code. But let's try:

```
trait Bar<'a> {
    fn bar(&self, x: &'a u8);
}
```

This is similar to the `bar()` function above, but now the lifetime parameter is defined on the trait, not the function. Let's use the trait:

```
fn use_bar<'a, B: Bar<'a>>(b: B) {
    let local = 0u8;
    b.bar(&local);
}
```

This doesn't compile, printing the same error as above. Why? The method `b.bar()` expects a reference of lifetime `'a`. But who chooses `'a` here? Exactly: the *caller* -- the *caller* **of `use_bar()`**, not the caller of `bar()`! So the caller of `use_bar()` could choose the `'static` lifetime; in that case, it's easy to see that our `&local` doesn't fulfill the lifetime requirements.

Note that the *caller* of `use_bar()` chooses `'a` as well as `B`. Once `use_bar()` is instantiated, `B` is a fixed type and `B::bar()` works only for one specific lifetime. This means the caller of `bar()` can't choose the lifetime, but `bar()` itself chose it!

What do we want instead? We want `use_bar()` to choose the lifetime of the `bar()` call. And we can do that with the `for<>` syntax:

```
fn use_bar<B: for<'a> Bar<'a>>(b: B) {
    let local = 0u8;
    b.bar(&local);
}
```

This works. What we say here is: "for any lifetime parameter `'a`, `B` has to implement the trait `Bar<'a>`". Instead of: "there needs to exist a lifetime parameter `'a` for which `B` implements `Bar<'a>`". It's all about who chooses which parameter.

Let's use the real names for it:

- a generic parameter is **universally quantified** if the *caller* can choose it
- a generic parameter is **existentially quantified** if the *callee* can choose it

#### What does Rust do?

To return to your example:

```
fn get<'inp, F: Fn(&'inp [u8]) -> u8>(f: F) -> u8 {
    f(&[1, 2, 3])
}
```

Here we have the same problem as above: the lifetime parameter of `f` is existentially quantified. The caller of `f` cannot choose the lifetime parameter. We can fix that with the `for<>` syntax as shown above.

When you omit the lifetimes:

```
fn get<F: Fn(&[u8]) -> u8>(f: F) -> u8 {
    f(&[1, 2, 3])
}
```

The Rust compiler will do something special for the `Fn` family of traits.  Your `F: Fn(&[u8])` desugars to `F: for<'a> Fn<(&'a [u8],)>`. If you use `Fn*` traits with parameters that involve lifetimes, those lifetimes are automatically *universally* quantified, because that's usually what you want with higher order functions.

Comment: *"So here foo() is generic over the type T. "* - I think you dropped some context there

Comment: @the8472 Thanks! :) I fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

The infered code seems to be:

```
fn get<F : for<'inp> Fn(&'inp[u8]) -> u8>(f: F) -> u8 {
    f(&[1,2,3])
}
```

[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound)