# How to write a trait bound for a reference to an associated type on the trait itself?

Tags: generics, rust, constraints, traits, serde

I have this code:

```
extern crate serde;

use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use serde::Serialize;

trait Bar<'a, T: 'a>
where
    T: Serialize,
    &'a T: DeserializeOwned,
{
}
```

I would like to write this using an associated type, because the type `T` is unimportant to the users of this type. I got this far:

```
trait Bar {
    type T: Serialize;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to specify the other bound.

Ultimately, I want to use a function like this:

```
extern crate serde_json;

fn test<I: Bar>(t: I::T) -> String {
    serde_json::to_string(&t).unwrap()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The "correct" solution is to place the bounds on the trait, but referencing the associated type. In this case, you can also use [higher ranked trait bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423) to handle the reference:

```
trait Bar
where
    Self::T: Serialize,
//  ^^^^^^^ Bounds on an associated type  
    for<'a> &'a Self::T: DeserializeOwned,
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ Higher-ranked trait bounds       
{
    type T;
}
```

However, this doesn't work yet.

I believe that you will need to either:

- wait for [issue 20671](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671) and/or [issue 50346](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50346) to be fixed.
- wait for the [*generic associated types*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) feature which introduces [`where` clauses on associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md#where-clauses-on-associated-types).

In the meantime, the workaround is to duplicate the bound everywhere it's needed:

```
fn test<I: Bar>(t: I::T) -> String
where
    for<'a> &'a I::T: DeserializeOwned,
{
    serde_json::to_string(&t).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know you could `Self` in that case. But it doesn't seem to work as I expected. I have this function: `fn test<I: Bar>(t: I::T) -> String { serde_json::to_string(&t).unwrap() }`. Compilation fails with "the trait `for<'a> DeserializeOwned` is not implemented for `&'a <I as Bar>::T`". I think that by requiring that t is a I::T, there must be a DeserializeOwned for &'a t forall 'a. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @corvus_192 I think that's because there's no `I` in the signature of `test` for the compiler to see. You could implement multiple types `I` for which `<I as Bar>::T` was the same thing, right?

Comment: @trentcl In my case there's only one implementation of Bar, but there could obviously be more than one. Why does it matter, as long as every implementation provides a type T that satisfies the given bounds?

Comment: @corvus_192 The compiler is not very good at proving universal propositions. A signature like `fn test<I: Bar>(t: I::T) -> String` implies that you could pick *any* `I` that implements `Bar`, and the compiler has to prove that there is a `DeserializeOwned` impl for *every* `I` where `<I as Bar>::T` is whatever the type of `t` actually is. I'm doing a poor job of explaining. Point is, it's logically sound, but the compiler can't *prove* that there isn't some `I` for which `&<I as Bar>::T` *doesn't* implement `DeserializeOwned`.

Comment: The upshot of all this is that you have to duplicate the bound `for<'a> &'a I::T: DeserializeOwned` on `test` because just having it on `Bar` is not sufficient. [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f57f3c86590f5b1950f20f6f2d8e4235&version=stable&mode=debug)