# How do I constrain associated types on a non-owned trait?

Tags: syntax, rust, traits, associated-types

[Here is a link to this example in Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=585ba50191529ef423b5310ac16bc214&version=stable&mode=debug)

I am creating two traits. The one trait uses the other as an associated type. The associated trait extends `FromStr`:

```
trait Behaviour where Self: FromStr {}
trait AnotherBehaviour {
    type Assoc: Behaviour;
}
```

I can implement these traits for `Derp` and `AnotherDerp` respectively, remembering to implement `FromStr` for `Derp`:

```
struct Error {}
struct Derp {}
struct AnotherDerp {}

impl Behaviour for Derp {}
impl FromStr for Derp {
    type Err = Error;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s { "derp" => Ok(Derp{}), _ => Err(Error {}) }
    }
}

impl AnotherBehaviour for AnotherDerp {
    type Assoc = Derp;
}
```

Now I want to create a generic function that uses the encapsulating trait.

```
fn run<T: AnotherBehaviour>() {
    let derp = T::Assoc::from_str("derp").expect("expected derp");
}

fn main() {
    run::<AnotherDerp>();
}
```

I get the error:

```
note: the method `expect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
       `<<T as AnotherBehaviour>::Assoc as std::str::FromStr>::Err : std::fmt::Debug`
```

I implement `Debug` for my `Error` type:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Error {}
```

But this won't work because I actually need to constrain the trait.

I know that I can constrain the generic function with

```
where
    <T::Assoc as FromStr>::Err: Debug,
```

but how can I constrain the `Behaviour` or `AnotherBehaviour` trait to require `FromStr::Err` to implement `Debug`? I can't figure out the syntax.

I have tried

```
trait Behaviour: FromStr
where
     <Self as FromStr>::Err: Debug
```

and

```
trait Behaviour: FromStr
where
    Self::Err: Debug
```

Comment: `trait Behaviour where Self: FromStr,` -> `trait Behaviour: FromStr`.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to write a bound for a reference to an associated type on the trait itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50090578/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: The above edits still don't seem to work. Is this possible?

Comment: I edited the answer to be more clear. That syntax is correct (although verbose: `Self::Err: Debug` is sufficient) but support for it is not implemented.

Comment: Thats disappointing, okay.