# How to deserialize messages within Actix actors?

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-actix

My intention is receiving events through WebSockets and use them on the closures of `main`.
This works when the messages are pure text (`String`), but the idea is deserializing that text into some structs.

In this example I've added only `Data`, `Error` and `Event`, but in other cases, it could be different, so I've used generics to do that, but I'm a little lost. The compiler has suggested several things that I've tried, but I don't know how to "force" that the message is casted into a specific type (`Data` in this example, but `EventManager` could be used on other parts, so it should be generic).

I've attached this code, that tries to show my idea, although it doesn't compile:

`events.rs`:

```
use actix::*;
use actix_web::ws::{Client, Message, ProtocolError};
use futures::Future;

use serde::de;
use serde_json::from_str;

struct MyActor<T> {
    manager: EventManager<T>,
}

impl<T: 'static> Actor for MyActor<T> {
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}

impl<T: 'static> StreamHandler<Message, ProtocolError> for MyActor<T> {
    fn handle(&mut self, msg: Message, _ctx: &mut Context<Self>) {
        match msg {
            Message::Text(text) => {
                debug!("Received {}", text);

                for idx in 0..self.manager.events.len() {
                    let data =
                        from_str(&text).expect(&format!("Error when deserializing {:?}", text));
                    (self.manager.events[idx].handler)(data)
                }
            }
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }
}

pub struct Event<T> {
    handler: Box<Fn(T) + 'static>,
}

pub struct EventManager<T> {
    events: Vec<Event<T>>,
}

impl<T: 'static> EventManager<T>
where
    T: serde::Deserialize<'static>,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { events: vec![] }
    }

    pub fn capture<F>(&mut self, function: F)
    where
        F: for<'h> Fn(T) + 'static,
    {
        let event = Event {
            handler: Box::new(function),
        };
        self.events.push(event);
    }

    pub fn run(self) {
        let runner = System::new("example");

        debug!("run");

        Arbiter::spawn(
            Client::new("example")
                .connect()
                .map(|(reader, _writer)| {
                    MyActor::create(|ctx| {
                        MyActor::add_stream(reader, ctx);
                        MyActor { manager: self }
                    });
                })
                .map_err(|err| {}),
        );

        runner.run();
    }
}
```

`main.rs`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
extern crate actix;
extern crate actix_web;
extern crate env_logger;
extern crate futures;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

pub mod events;

use actix::*;
use serde::de;
use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

use events::EventManager;

#[derive(Debug, Message, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Data {
    Error(Error),
    Event(Event),
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Error {
    message: String,
    code: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Event {
    name: String,
    content: String,
}

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    let mut client = EventManager::<Data>new();

    client.capture(|data| debug!("event: {:?}", data));
    client.run();
}
```

All the code could be see in https://github.com/foochi/how-deserialize-within-actix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some fixes to get it compile.

The trick to get it compile is to use [Higher-Rank Trait Bounds (HTRB)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) trait bounds instead of declaring `'static` lifetimes.

Follow the compiler suggestion and bind the `T: serde::Deserialize<'_>` trait:

```
impl<T> StreamHandler<Message, ProtocolError> for MyActor<T>
where
    for<'de> T: serde::Deserialize<'de> + 'static,
```

Then change also the `Deserialize<'static>` trait bound associated to the`EventManager` impl with a HTRB trait bound to get it compatible with the requirement of `StreamHandler` implementation:

```
impl<T: 'static> EventManager<T>
where
    for<'de> T: serde::Deserialize<'de>,
```

Finally, if you correct the line the create the client with the right sintax:

```
let mut client: EventManager<Data> = EventManager::new();
```

the example code should compile.

Note: For `capture` the use of a Higher Trait Bound for declaring the `Fn` requirement is redundant, do simply:

```
pub fn capture<F>(&mut self, function: F)
where
    F: Fn(T) + 'static,
```

Comment: Thank you.

This other question, could be useful for understanding HTRB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound/35595491#35595491