# Wrong trait chosen based on type parameter

Tags: rust

I have a binary trait `Resolve`.

```
pub trait Resolve<RHS = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn resolve(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
}
```

I implemented the trait for something trivial where both arguments are taken by reference (`self` is `&'a Foo` and `rhs` is `&'b Foo`):

```
struct Foo;

impl <'a, 'b> Resolve<&'b Foo> for &'a Foo {
    type Output = Foo;
    fn resolve(self, rhs: &'b Foo) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

If I now write

```
fn main() {
    let a: &Foo = &Foo;
    let b = Foo;
    a.resolve(&b);
}
```

it will compile just fine, but if I try to implement it on my struct `Signal`, it will not work.

```
pub struct Signal<'a, T> {
    ps: Vec<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T: Resolve<&'a T, Output = T> + 'a> Signal<'a, T> {
    pub fn foo(&mut self) {
        let a: &T = &self.ps[0];
        let b = &self.ps[1];
        a.resolve(b);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
25 |         a.resolve(b);
   |         ^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How do I get this example working? ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f427b1d07ba980641d4aa59ab5102492))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trait bound on `foo` only says that `T` implements `Resolve`, but you try to call `.resolve()` on a value of type `&T`.

To say, instead, that *references* to `T` must implement `Resolve`, you need a [higher-ranked trait bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound):

```
impl<'a, T> Signal<'a, T>
where
    for<'b> &'b T: Resolve<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    pub fn foo(&mut self) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this I came up with a simpler solution that does not rely on HRTB.

```
impl<'a, T> Signal<'a, T>
where
    &'a T: Resolve<&'a T, Output = T> + 'a,
{
    pub fn foo(&mut self) {
        let a: &T = &self.ps[0];
        let b = &self.ps[1];
        a.resolve(b);
    }
}
```

This does the same, namely describe, that `&T` implements `Resolve`, but without the need of HRTB.
You have to use the [where clause](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/traits.html#where-clause) for this, but apart from that this is a nice and easy solution.

Comment: You are right, it does work in this case because `&'a T` is `Copy` (note that the `&` in `&self.ps[0]` does not do anything and can be deleted). In a more complex scenario, where you had to reborrow with the lifetime of `self`, you would need HRTBs.