# Trait implementation with where clauses: Implementing a simple where clause

Tags: types, rust, traits

I have been trying to learn Rust through [rust-koans](https://github.com/crazymykl/rust-koans) but ran into a wall with the following trait koan:

```
// There is an alternate syntax for placing trait bounds on a function, the
// where clause. Let's revisit a previous example, this time using 'where'.
#[test]
fn where_clause() {
    let num_one: u16 = 3;
    let num_two: u16 = 4;

    trait IsEvenOrOdd {
        fn is_even(&self) -> bool;
    }

    impl IsEvenOrOdd for u16 {
        fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
            self % 2 == 0
        }
    }

    fn asserts<T>(x: T, y: T) {
        assert!(!x.is_even());
        assert!(y.is_even());
    }

    asserts(num_one, num_two);
}
```

It seems the goal is to complete this code by creating a generic version of the `IsEvenOrOdd` implementation. In this case the generic type should have two bounds, the remainder operator and the `PartialEq` operator. Because the remainder right side and equivalence right side are integers, I eventually wrote the following spaghetti code:

```
use std::ops::Rem;

impl<T> IsEvenOrOdd for T
where
    T: Rem<u16> + Rem,
    <T as Rem<u16>>::Output: PartialEq<u16>,
{
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
        self % 2 == 0
    }
}
```

Still - the code doesn't compile. It seems that since `T` is dereferenced I would need to add bounds to the dereferenced value, but I cannot find any example of how to do that.

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `%` cannot be applied to type `&T`
   --> src\koans/traits.rs:142:13
    |
142 |             self % 2 == 0
    |             ^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Rem` might be missing for `&T`
```

In short: What would be the idiomatic Rust way to solve this koan?

Comment: "It seems the goal is to complete this code by createing a generic version of the IsEvenOrOdd implementation." Is it? I would assume the goal is just to add a `where` clause so that the code compiles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong trait choosen based on type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125347/wrong-trait-choosen-based-on-type-parameter)

Comment: I agree; to solve the koan, add `where T: IsEvenOrOdd` to `fn asserts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misinterpreted the intention of this exercise. What you want is this:

```
fn main() {
    let num_one: u16 = 3;
    let num_two: u16 = 4;

    trait IsEvenOrOdd {
        fn is_even(&self) -> bool;
    }

    impl IsEvenOrOdd for u16 {
        fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
            self % 2 == 0
        }
    }

    fn asserts<T>(x: T, y: T)
        where T: IsEvenOrOdd {
        assert!(!x.is_even());
        assert!(y.is_even());
    }

    asserts(num_one, num_two);
}
```

How did I come to this conclusion? Trying to compile and run the original code you posted results in the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `is_even` found for type `T` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:16:20
   |
16 |         assert!(!x.is_even());
   |                    ^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `is_even`, perhaps you need to implement it:
       candidate #1: `main::IsEvenOrOdd`
```

This error tells us that to call the `is_even` method, you must implement `IsEvenOrOdd`. The comments on the top of the example you posted say to use the `where` clause on a *function*. Adding the `where` clause to the function `asserts` solves your problem and completes the exercise.