# Cannot build equivalent closure for a function when the closure contains complex lifetime relationships

Tags: rust

I've got some trouble with replacing function with equivalent closure, compiler complaining

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements

note: ...so that the types are compatible:
      expected &std::collections::BTreeSet<&str>
         found &std::collections::BTreeSet<&str> rustc(E0495)
```

in the closure, at the `range`method in `r.extend(s.range(lower..=upper));`.
But i can't figure out how to put lifetime hint in a closure, and maybe, it's not possible.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn main() {
    let mut set = BTreeSet::new();

    set.insert("TEST1");
    set.insert("TEST3");
    set.insert("TEST4");
    set.insert("TEST2");
    set.insert("TEST5");

    println!("init: {:?}", set);

    let closure = |lower, upper| {        
        |s: &BTreeSet<&str>| {
            let mut r = BTreeSet::new();
            r.extend(s.range(lower..=upper));
            r
        }
    };

    set = extract_fn("TEST2", "TEST5")(&set);
    set = closure("TEST3", "TEST4")(&set);
    println!("result: {:?}", set);
}

fn extract_fn<'a>(
    lower: &'a str,
    upper: &'a str,
) -> impl Fn(&BTreeSet<&'a str>) -> BTreeSet<&'a str> {
    move |s| {
        let mut r = BTreeSet::new();
        r.extend(s.range(lower..=upper));
        r
    }
}
```

Except putting `static` lifetime, should a closure with this type of error be transformed to a function ?

Comment: @Shepmaster not sure about duplicate, and IMHO, the answer with `for<>` may be interesting for broad range of lifetime problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done easily but you can define your outer closure with a return type which helps you to set explicit lifetime boundaries for your inner closure. (By using `for<>` which is a  Higher Ranked Trait Bound, you can find more [details in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound)).

Inner closure needed to be `Box`ed because the size of `Fn` trait is not known at compile time.

```
let closure = |lower, upper| -> Box<for<'a> Fn(&BTreeSet<&'a str>) -> BTreeSet<&'a str>> {
        Box::new(move |s: &BTreeSet<&str>| {
            let mut r = BTreeSet::new();
            r.extend(s.range(lower..=upper));
            r
        })
    };
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ceead2113ef686d337989dcf9776c76e)