# Compiler complains about missing PhantomData when a lifetime is only needed for another trait parameter

Tags: rust, lifetime

```rust
use tokio::io::AsyncWrite;

pub enum Out<'a, T>
where
    T: AsyncWrite + Unpin,
{
    V(Bar<'a, T>),
}

pub struct Bar<'a, T: AsyncWrite + Unpin> {
    tx: &'a mut T,
}

trait Foo<'m, T: AsyncWrite + Unpin> {
    fn foo(&mut self, m: &u8) -> Result<Out<'m, T>, ()>;
}

struct Inner2<'m, T, S>
where
    T: AsyncWrite + Unpin,
    S: Foo<'m, T>,
{
    response_sender: S,
    _t: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}
```

Here's the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=098b94b3437360c4f4128a0f0cdf20cf)

```
error[E0392]: parameter `'m` is never used
  --> src/lib.rs:18:15
   |
18 | struct Inner2<'m, T, S>
   |               ^^ unused parameter
   |
   = help: consider removing `'m`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`
```

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2e4e5fc579bf2edb6d7b2b03d88f47d), or [applied a different way](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6510c1dcbbdd251fd9be8a1d9837138) or don't place the trait bound on the struct but only the *function* that needs it.

Comment: Both solutions achieve different effect right? What does <&'m ()> mean in 2nd solution? What is it doing? @Shepmaster

Comment: *achieve different effect* — Yes, all three solutions have different effects. [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423). *What does <&'m ()> mean* — It means the same conceptual thing as the `PhantomData` you are already using: "tell the compiler to treat this type as if it contained a reference to a value with lifetime `'m`".