# Issue with lifetime parameters and function pointers

Tags: rust

Consider this code:

```
struct WithLifetime<'a> {
    s: &'a str
}

impl WithLifetime<'_> {
    fn in_impl(&self) -> bool {
        self.s == "a"
    }
}

fn out_of_impl(wl: &WithLifetime<'_>) -> bool {
    wl.s == "a"
}

fn higher_order(f: fn(&WithLifetime<'_>) -> bool) -> bool {
    let s = "a";
    let wl = WithLifetime { s };
    f(&wl)
}

fn main() {
    higher_order(out_of_impl); // This line compiles
    higher_order(WithLifetime::in_impl); // This line does not
}
```

The final line of `main` fails to compile with this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:18
   |
23 |     higher_order(WithLifetime::in_impl); // This line does not
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r WithLifetime<'s>) -> _`
              found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r WithLifetime<'_>) -> _`
```

As far as I can figure out, `in_impl` and `out_of_impl` should be exactly the same function. They both take a reference to a `WithLifetime`, and don't care about the lifetime of that reference or the lifetime parameter of the `WithLifetime` instance. Both should be valid parameters to pass to `higher_order`. The compiler does not agree.

What is the problem with passing `in_impl` to `higher_order`, and why doesn't the compiler allow this? What can I do to pass struct methods on structs with lifetime parameters to higher-order functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's find out the types for all the 3 functions:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: i32 = out_of_impl;
    let x: i32 = WithLifetime::in_impl;
    let x: i32 = higher_order;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d54d18c5d49ef65fa3d643f05287910e)

Type of `out_of_impl`:

```rust
for<'r, 's> fn(&'r WithLifetime<'s>) -> bool {out_of_impl}
```

Type of `WithLifetime::in_impl`:

```rust
for<'r> fn(&'r WithLifetime<'_>) -> bool {WithLifetime::<'_>::in_impl}
```

Type of `higher_order`:

```rust
fn(for<'r, 's> fn(&'r WithLifetime<'s>) -> bool) -> bool {higher_order}
```

`higher_order` accepts a function in which both the lifetimes aren't named until the function is called.
So it basically accepts a function which works for any lifetimes `'r` and `'s`. `out_of_impl` satisfies that criteria.

But in case of `WithLifetime::in_impl`, the inner lifetime needs to be known beforehand `for<'r> fn(&'r WithLifetime<'_>)`.

To pass `WithLifetime::in_impl`, you would need to change it to:

```rust
fn in_impl<'b, 'c>(abc: &'b WithLifetime<'c>) -> bool {
    abc.s == "a"
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe626d62cb7f59f1ba4a6d1898ed0dc9)

Now, this function works for any arbitrary lifetimes `'b` and `'c`.

---

To accept `in_impl` without changing it, as @[Milan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65117844/11498773) did,

```rust
fn higher_order<'b>(f: fn(&WithLifetime<'b>) -> bool) -> bool {
    let s = "a";
    let wl = WithLifetime { s };
    f(&wl)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=640e31e03305d57aab3d67ec4d9feadd)

Now, `higher_order` has a type:

```rust
for<'b> fn(for<'r> fn(&'r WithLifetime<'b>) -> bool) -> bool {higher_order}
```

It accepts a function where lifetime `'r` is defined only when the function is called and liftime `'b` is known beforehand.

This works for `out_of_impl` because it accepts any arbitrary lifetimes. Also works for `in_impl` because now the signature matches `higher_order`.

[How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound) has a pretty nice explaination for HRTB.

Answer (score 1):

In `higher_order` function, `wl` is dropped before it is borrowed, instead, change that function to this

```rust
fn higher_order<'b>(f: fn(&WithLifetime<'b>) -> bool) -> bool {
    let s = "a";
    let wl= WithLifetime { s };
    f(&wl)
}
```

EDIT:

In simple words, `fn higher_order<'b>(f: fn(&WithLifetime<'b>) -> bool) -> bool` this **'b** means that `higher_order` body lifetime will match `fn` lifetime.

Otherwise, if `fn` don't care what lifetime `higher_order` has, and this implicitly means `wl` value too since it is the body of high_order function, then compiler can drop `wl` at the same line it is declared since point is to save memory, right?

Comment: Would expect a little more explaination.

Comment: I hope edit explains better what change means to compiler

Comment: This does fix the issue with `in_impl` while still allowing it to be a trait method, however I'm not so sure about your explanation. `wl` cannot be dropped before it is borrowed, the compiler wouldn't allow that. And given your solution, the issue seems to be with the lifetime parameter on `WithLifetime`, not the lifetime of the reference to `wl` itself.