# How to find generic bounds for producer that creates objects with trait-lifetime bounds

Tags: rust, lifetime, trait-objects

I have reduced my actual code to this minimal example:

```
trait Producer<P> where P: Something {
    fn produce(&self) -> Box<P>;
}

struct P1 {}

impl Producer<B1> for P1 {
    fn produce(&self) -> Box<B1> {
        Box::new(B1 {})
    }
}

trait Something {}

trait Borrower<'b> {
    type B: std::fmt::Display;
    
    fn borrow(&'b self) -> Self::B;
}

struct B1 {}

impl Something for B1 {}

impl<'b> Borrower<'b> for B1 {
    type B = Borrowing1<'b>;
    
    fn borrow(&'b self) -> Self::B {
        Borrowing1 { _b: &self }
    }
}

struct Borrowing1<'b> {
    _b: &'b B1,
}

impl<'b> std::fmt::Display for Borrowing1<'b> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Borrowing1")
    }
}

fn perform<'b, P, B>(producer: P) where P: Producer<B>, B: Something + Borrower<'b> + 'static {
    for _ in 0..1 {
        let b = producer.produce();
        let s = b.borrow().to_string();
        eprintln!("{}", s);
    }
}

fn main() {
   let p1 = P1 {};
   perform(p1);
}
```

I have a `Producer` type that creates `Something`. And that something can implement `Borrower<'b>`, which introduces a lifetime. Then, I want to restrict a function `perform` to receive producers that produce `Something` with the trait `Borrower<'b>`. However, since I can't prevent introducing a lifetime in `perform` the function thinks that all produced items must live for the entire function execution. Actually, they are static objects that just implement `Borrower<'b>`. But I struggle finding the correct bounds.

The error message reflects that:

```
error[E0597]: `*b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:46:17
   |
43 | fn perform<'b, P, B>(producer: P) where P: Producer<B>, B: Something + Borrower<'b> + 'static {
   |            -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
46 |         let s = b.borrow().to_string();
   |                 ^---------
   |                 |
   |                 borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 argument requires that `*b` is borrowed for `'b`
47 |         eprintln!("{}", s);
48 |     }
   |     - `*b` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Maybe you can help me with that.

Comment: Using GAT in nightly it is surprisingly easy to do: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d2156040c803d54c857587c586bc390). I don't know of an easy workaround, though.

Comment: This kinda sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you please explain what actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved using [higher-rank trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html):

You don't have to pass a lifetime to function here. Instead you need to define a lifetime on the go when `borrow()` is called. Following should solve the issue:

```rust
fn perform<P, B>(producer: P)
where
    P: Producer<B>,
    for<'b> B: Something + Borrower<'b> + 'static,
{
    for _ in 0..1 {
        let b = producer.produce();
        let u = b.borrow();
        let s = u.to_string();
        eprintln!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=64c3b7452c6d28f5325cdf26114cebce)

Higher-rank trait bounds are explained pretty nicely here:
 [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound)

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you very much. I thought higher-rank trait bounds were unstable.