# lifetime of function pointer is for<'a, '_> while it should be for<'r>

Tags: rust, lifetime

Sometimes I struggle with lifetimes. I'm still learning and I don't know what's happening here:

```
use std::future::Future;
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};

struct M{}
struct Client{}

impl Client {
    async fn send_and_expect<'a>(
        &'a mut self,
        m: &M
    ) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    
    pub fn connection_retrier<'a, T>(
        f: fn(&'a mut Self, &M) -> T,
        f_self: &'a mut Self,
        f_m: &'a M,
    )-> BoxFuture<'a, std::result::Result<(),()>>
    where
        T: Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), ()>> + 'a
    {
        async move {
            Client::send_and_expect(f_self, f_m).await
        }.boxed()
    }
    
    async fn send_with_retry<'a>(&'a mut self) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
        let m = M{};
        Client::connection_retrier(
                    Client::send_and_expect, 
                    &mut *self, &m).await
    }
}
```

Error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:31:21
   |
11 |     ) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
   |          --------------------------- the `Output` of this `async fn`'s found opaque type
...
31 |                     Client::send_and_expect, 
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&mut Client, &'r M) -> impl futures::Future`
              found fn pointer `for<'a, '_> fn(&'a mut Client, &M) -> impl futures::Future
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a0a8f3c2e2de05a3e8dc55d5e65694cc)

I'm now completely confused about why in `for<'r> fn(&mut Client, &'r M) -> impl futures::Future`, `&mut Client` has no lifetime. And what does `_` means in  for<'a, '_> fn(&'a mut Client, &M) -> impl futures::Future`?

I'm very intersted in learning what's happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Cleaning up the code

In order to see this code from the compiler's perspective, let's change all the lifetime parameters in this example to be explicit and have distinct names, expand the `async fn` sugar, and then look at how the error changes.

The above example is equivalent to the following after lifetime inference and desugaring.

```
// name the second lifetime, and expand the async fn sugar.
fn send_and_expect<'a, 'b>(&'a mut self, m: &'b M) -> impl Future<Item=Result<(), ()>> + 'a + 'b 
{ ... }

// rename 'a to 'c to avoid ambiguous lifetime names
pub fn connection_retrier<'c, T>(
        f: for<'d> fn(&'c mut Self, &'d M) -> T, // name the implicit higher-ranked lifetime here
        f_self: &'c mut Self,
        f_m: &'c M,
    )-> BoxFuture<'c, std::result::Result<(), ()>>
where T: Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), ()>> + 'c 
{ ... }

// rename 'a to 'e to avoid ambiguous lifetime names
async fn send_with_retry<'e>(&'e mut self) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
```

After making this change, the error becomes:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:31:21
   |
11 |     ) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
   |          --------------------------- the `Output` of this `async fn`'s found opaque type
...
31 |                     Client::send_and_expect, 
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'d> fn(&mut Client, &'d M) -> impl futures::Future`
              found fn pointer `for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a mut Client, &'b M) -> impl futures::Future`
```

This should clarify your question about `'_`: it's just the name the compiler gave the inferred second lifetime parameter of `send_and_expect`. As for the missing lifetime on `&mut Client`, you can see that it's still missing here. For reasons I do not completely understand, and in ways that depend on the exact error message given, the compiler will sometimes omit concrete lifetimes when printing the type of references, but make no mistake, the lifetime of that reference *is* `'c`.

## Solving the error

Onto the actual problem. The signature of `f` indicates that `connection_retrier` is expecting a function which (1) takes a reference of lifetime `&'c` and (2) a reference of *any* other lifetime, and (3) returns a `Future` type which will remain valid as long as `'c` does, as specified by your `where` bound.

When we pass `send_and_expect` to `connection_retrier`, in order for the signatures to match the compiler is coercing it to the type `for<'d> send_and_expect::<'c, 'd>`. But that type doesn't meet condition (3) above! Unlike a regular function, the default behavior of an `async` function is to capture *all* input lifetimes in its return type, so the return type of `for<'d> send_and_expect::<'c, 'd>` is in fact `impl Future<Item=Result<(), ()>> + 'c + 'd`, as you can tell by looking at `send_and_expect`'s expanded signature.

Since this type borrows from the two lifetimes `'c` and `'d`, and there is no constraint that `'d: 'c` (read: `'d` outlives `'c`), it may not remain valid for the entirety of the lifetime `'c`, if `'d` ends first. It is this mismatch that results in the rather cryptic lifetime error you received. There are two ways you can solve this problem, depending on your preferred semantics. You can either:

- Remove the higher-ranked bound from `f` entirely, and specify exactly the lifetimes you will be calling it with in `connection_retrier` (both `&'c`.)

  ```
  pub fn connection_retrier<'c, T>(
          f: fn(&'c mut Self, &'c M) -> T
          f_self: &'c mut Self,
          f_m: &'c M,
      ) -> BoxFuture<'c, std::result::Result<(), ()>>
  where T: Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), ()>> + 'c 
  { ... }
  ```
- Keep the signature of `connection_retrier` the same and specify that the future returned by `send_and_expect` only borrows from its first argument. To do this, you will need to drop the `async fn` sugar on the signature and wrap the body in an `async move` block.

  ```
  fn send_and_expect<'a, 'b>(&'a mut self, m: &'b M) -> impl Future<Output=Result<(), ()>> + 'a 
  { async move { ... } }
  ```

Note that you *cannot* solve this by writing the type of `f` as `for<'d: 'c> fn(&'c mut Self, &'d M) -> T`, as bounds are currently not permitted for universally quantified lifetimes.

Comment: I wants to run the above code to understand easier, and when i compile the clean up code, `fn send_and_expect<'a, 'b>(&'a mut self, m: &'b M) -> impl Future<Item=Result<(), ()>> + 'a + 'b` , `Result<(), _>` is not a future` happend. Maybe I use incorrect `futures` version? `futures = "0.3.14"`. I do not know how to solve this error. Can you help me.

Comment: @AsceticBear Oops, my bad. The name of that associated type is `Output`, not `Item`. I'll edit the answer. Also, be sure to wrap the body in `async move { }`.

Comment: Thanks for your guides, wrap `Ok(())` with `async move {}` works. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for such an amazing answer. Could you explain better to me why the function signature suddenly has `for<'a, 'b>`? What does this mean exactly and why the signature of a function pointer has it?

Comment: @Gatonito If you are just asking why it changed from `for<'a, '_>` to `for<'a, 'b>` in the error, it's because lifetime inference automatically created a lifetime parameter for the second reference in the signature of `send_and_expect`. Since this parameter had no name initially, the compiler referred to it as `'_`.

Comment: @Gatonito If it's the concept of `for<'lifetime>` itself you're asking about, I recommend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound. When you write a `fn` type, the compiler will implicitly quantify (`for<>`) over reference arguments for which no lifetime is specified.

Comment: I opted for the first solution, as the second can't be used because `send_and_expect` is recursive, so it cannot return an `impl Future`, it must return a `BoxFuture`. However, this brings me a new error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239248/recursive-async-function-that-borrows-mutable-variable-twice. Do you have an idea on what I can do?

Comment: on this question I didn't make it recursive but it is

Comment: I think I'm really stuck in the concept of `pub fn connection_retrier<'a, T>(
    f: fn(&'a mut Self, &'a Message) -> T,`. First I thought `fn` was the signature for a function generic over the lifetime of the arguments, but now I see it as a function that receives arguments with the exact lifetime `'a`. However, I don't see why, in my new question above, when I call `f`, `f_self` needs to be borrowed for `'a`. It could only be borrowed for as long `f` needs it. Then it could be borrowed again

Comment: @Gatonito Hi. This discussion is getting a little unwieldy for these comments, and it seems like your question is more complex than initially posed. Would you like to discuss further in chat? Here's a link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231556/recursive-async-functions-and-lifetimes-chat