# Lifetime of get method in postgres Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

**Some Background (feel free to skip):**

I'm very new to Rust, I come from a Haskell background (just in case that gives you an idea of any misconceptions I might have).

I am trying to write a program which, given a bunch of inputs from a database, can create customisable reports. To do this I wanted to create a `Field` datatype which is composable in a sort of DSL style. In Haskell my intuition would be to make `Field` an instance of `Functor` and `Applicative` so that writing things like this would be possible:

```hs
type Env = [String]
type Row = [String]

data Field a = Field
    { fieldParse :: Env -> Row -> a }

instance Functor Field where
    fmap f a = Field $
        \env row -> f $ fieldParse a env row

instance Applicative Field where
    pure = Field . const . const
    fa <*> fb = Field $
        \env row -> (fieldParse fa) env row
            $ (fieldParse fb) env row

oneField :: Field Int
oneField = pure 1

twoField :: Field Int
twoField = fmap (*2) oneField

tripleField :: Field (Int -> Int)
tripleField = pure (*3)

threeField :: Field Int
threeField = tripleField <*> oneField
```

**Actual Question:**

I know that it's quite awkward to implement `Functor` and `Applicative` traits in Rust so I just implemented the appropriate functions for `Field` rather than actually defining traits (this all compiled fine). Here's a very simplified implementation of `Field` in Rust, without any of the `Functor` or `Applicative` stuff.

```rust
use std::result;
use postgres::Row;
use postgres::types::FromSql;

type Env = Vec<String>;

type FieldFunction<A> = Box<dyn Fn(&Env, &Row) -> Result<A, String>>;

struct Field<A> {
    field_parse: FieldFunction<A>
}
```

I can easily create a function which simply gets the value from an input field and creates a report `Field` with it:

```rust
fn field_good(input: u32) -> Field<String> {
    let f = Box::new(move |_: &Env, row: &Row| {
        Ok(row.get(input as usize))
    });

    Field { field_parse: f }
}
```

But when I try to make this polymorphic rather than using `String` I get some really strange lifetime errors that I just don't understand:

```rust
fn field_bad<'a, A: FromSql<'a>>(input: u32) -> Field<A> {
    let f = Box::new(move |_: &Env, row: &Row| {
        Ok(row.get(input as usize))
    });

    Field { field_parse: f }
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/test.rs:36:16
   |
36 |         Ok(row.get(input as usize))
   |                ^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 35:22...
  --> src/test.rs:35:22
   |
35 |       let f = Box::new(move |_: &Env, row: &Row| {
   |  ______________________^
36 | |         Ok(row.get(input as usize))
37 | |     });
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/test.rs:36:12
   |
36 |         Ok(row.get(input as usize))
   |            ^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 34:14...
  --> src/test.rs:34:14
   |
34 | fn field_bad<'a, A: FromSql<'a>>(input: FieldId) -> Field<A> {
   |              ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/test.rs:36:16
   |
36 |         Ok(row.get(input as usize))
   |                ^^^
   = note: expected `FromSql<'_>`
              found `FromSql<'a>`
```

Any help explaining what this error is actually getting at or how to potentially fix it would be much appreciated. I included the Haskell stuff so that my design intentions are clear, that way if the problem is that I'm using a programming style that doesn't really work in Rust, then that could be pointed out to me.

EDIT:
Forgot to include a link to the docs for `postgres::Row::get` in case it's relevant. They can be found [here](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.19.1/postgres/row/struct.Row.html#method.get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Higher-ranked trait bounds

I'm not familiar with the postgresql crate being used, so I can't give any general guidance on the approach the code is taking.

But anyway, sticking to the immediate problem with lifetimes in the current implementation, higher-ranked trait bounds might be workable. I would need a working example to confirm this though.

This is a new one for me. I tried out your code, and got some interesting error message indicating use of `for` in declaring bounds. Which brought me [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds) in the Rust Reference.

So I gave it a try, and it compiles.

```
fn field_bad<A>(input: u32) -> Field<A> 
where A: for<'a> FromSql<'a>
{
    let f = Box::new(move |_: &Env, row: &Row| {
        Ok(row.get(input as usize))
    });

    Field { field_parse: f }
}
```

This [section in the Rustnomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/hrtb.html) talks about HRTB's.

And this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound) talks about how lifetimes and higher-ranked trait bounds differ.

What it looks like is happening here is `field_bad()` isn't returning any `FromSql` instances - either directly or indirectly via `Field`. `FromSql` is just part of the `Ok(T)` return type of the closure, which exists as a field in `Field`. So the `for<..>` syntax is allowing us to provide the lifetime that applies to the type the closure *will* return when invoked.

Comment: That did indeed compile, thanks! I'm not going to pretend that I understand why but I'll give the other docs you linked a read and hopefully then it will make sense.

Comment: Ok so having read the SO post you liked on HRTBs I think I am starting to understand (sort of) what's going on.

Comment: @JamesBurton  were you able to get your code working with this approach? BTW, I don't think it started making a whole lot of sense for me until I read over parts of each of the refs I linked.

Comment: The code compiles but I can't confirm that it 100% works as intended until I sort out a few other things but I'll be sure to leave an update here.

Comment: Can confirm that the code runs as required.

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have fixed it, although I'm still not sure I understand exactly what I've done...

```rust
type FieldFunction<'a, A> = Box<dyn Fn(&Env, &'a Row) -> Result<A, String>>;

struct Field<'a, A> {
    field_parse: FieldFunction<'a, A>
}

fn field_bad<'a, A: FromSql<'a>>(input: u32) -> Field<'a, A> {
    let f = Box::new(move |_: &Env, row: &'a Row| {
        Ok(row.get(input as usize))
    });

    Field { field_parse: f }
}
```

I also swear I tried this several times before but there we are...