# Captured references in lifetimes

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

In (an artificial simplification of) my project, I have a struct `ContainsData` which can only be modified through a handle `HoldsRef<'a>`, which holds a ref to some field in `ContainsData`. In addition, after use of the handle, some `cleanup` method must be called.

```rust
struct ContainsData(i64);
impl ContainsData {
    fn cleanup(&mut self) {
        self.0 = self.0.abs();
    }
}

struct HoldsRef<'a>(&'a mut i64);
impl<'a> HoldsRef<'a> {
    fn set(&mut self, value: &'a i64) {
        *self.0 += value; 
    }
}

// A typical interaction with "ContainsData"
fn main() {
    let mut container = ContainsData(5);
    let x = 32;

    let mut handle = HoldsRef(&mut container.0);     // _
    handle.set(&x);                                  // |  A    
    handle.set(&31);                                 // |
    container.cleanup()                              // v
}
```

I would like to replace A with a single method call to `ContainsData`. All modifications to the handle will be done in the context of closure as follows:

```rust
impl ContainsData {
    fn modify(&mut self, continuation : impl Fn(HoldsRef)) {
        let handle = HoldsRef(&mut self.0); 
        continuation(handle);
        self.cleanup()
    }
}

fn main2() {
    let mut container = ContainsData(5);
    let x = 32;

    container.modify(|mut handle| {
        handle.set(&x);
        handle.set(&32);
    });
}
```

This does not compile:

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:56:21
   |
55 |     container.modify(|mut handle| {
   |                      ------------ value captured here
56 |         handle.set(&x);
   |         ------------^-
   |         |           |
   |         |           borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'static`
...
59 | }
   | - `x` dropped here while still borrowed
```

First question: why does Rust consider that `x` is borrowed for `'static`? I assume it has to do with the elision rule for `Fn(HoldsRef)` but I can't quite figure it out what the rule says in that case.

Second question: is there a way to change the signature of `modify` or alter the code a little bit to be able to replace A with a single method call ? I have tried to annotate lifetimes in various to no avail.

```rust
fn modify<'a>(&mut self, continuation : impl Fn(HoldsRef<'a>))
// cannot infer an appropriate lifetime (b/c, I guess, the handle has a lifetime strictly smaller than the function)
```

**Broader context:** `HoldsRef<'a>` is actually [wgpu::RenderPass<'a>](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.RenderPass.html). I don't have the option to change the signature of the method `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Found a partial solution below.

---

Let's understand what's going on here.

Lifetimes in closures (`impl Fn(&T)`, and also `impl Fn(T<'_>)`, which is the same as yours `impl Fn(HoldsRef)`), *do not* desugar into generic lifetimes like normal elided lifetimes (where `fn foo(_: &T)` desugars into `fn foo<'a>(_: &'a T)`); instead, they're desugared into [higher ranked trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html).

That is, `impl Fn(&T)` desugars into `impl for<'a> Fn(&'a T)`, and in the same manner, `impl Fn(HoldsRef)` desugars into `impl for<'a> Fn(HoldsRef<'a>)`. See also [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound).

HRTB (Higher-Ranked Traits Bounds) means that the lifetime can be *any* lifetime. And "any lifetime" includes, of course, `'static`. And because `'static` is the longest lifetime possible, the compiler just use this as if you've written `impl Fn(HoldsRef<'static>)`. Note **this is only true from the callback's point of view**, that is, the callback must be able to handle this case but `modify()` can call it with whatever lifetime it wants, not only static (as opposed to what would happen if you'd specify `impl Fn(HoldsRef<'static>)`, then you'd have to pass a `HoldsRef<'static>`).

Because the `HoldsRef::set()` method takes `&'a i64`, and `'a` is `'static`, so it's like it takes `&'static i64`. Now you will understand why the compiler complains when you provide a shorter lifetime.

You may think that the solution is just to take a generic lifetime instead of HRTB, and tie it to `self`:

```rust
fn modify<'a>(&'a mut self, continuation: impl Fn(HoldsRef<'a>)) {
```

However it doesn't work:

```rust
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
16 |     fn modify<'a>(&'a mut self, continuation: impl Fn(HoldsRef<'a>)) {
   |               -- lifetime `'a` defined here
17 |         let handle = HoldsRef(&mut self.0);
   |                               ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
18 |         continuation(handle);
   |         -------------------- argument requires that `self.0` is borrowed for `'a`
19 |         self.cleanup();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

And this makes sense: since we tell the compiler that the callback takes a `HoldsRef<'a>`, it can be alive when we `cleanup()`; and because this `HoldsRef` borrows `self.0`, we still hold a mutable reference to `self.0` while cleaning up.

---

**Edit:** I found a solution! This is not a direct solution to the problem, but rather some kind of workaround over it.

You can `impl Drop for HoldsRef`, and, in this impl, call `cleanup()`. That means you'll have to hold a reference to the entire `ContainsData` and not just its value. Like:

```rust
impl ContainsData {
    fn modify<'a>(&'a mut self, continuation: impl Fn(HoldsRef<'a>)) {
        let handle = HoldsRef(self);
        continuation(handle);
    }
}

struct HoldsRef<'a>(&'a mut ContainsData);

impl<'a> HoldsRef<'a> {
    fn set(&mut self, value: &'a i64) {
        self.0.0 += value;
    }
}

impl Drop for HoldsRef<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.0.cleanup();
    }
}
```

This also allows you to use RAII-style instead of callback-style, which is usually considered more idiomatic Rust:

```rust
impl ContainsData {
    fn get_handle(&mut self) -> HoldsRef<'_> {
        HoldsRef(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = ContainsData(5);
    let x = 32;

    // A block just to make dropping explicit.
    {
        let mut handle = container.get_handle();
        handle.set(&x);
        handle.set(&32);
    }
}
```