# traits bounds not satisfied on filter count method

Tags: rust

I am practicing using closures in rust, but the second of these 2 codes does not work... when I **extract** the **closure**, the compiler tells me that some **traits** are not **satisfied**

this code work

```
let invalids = s.chars().filter(|c| c == &'a').count();
```

but not this one

```
let is_invalid = |c| c == &'a';
let invalids = s.chars().filter(is_invalid).count();
```

this gives me the following error

```
error[E0599]: the method `count` exists for struct `Filter<Chars<'_>, [closure@src/main.rs:4:24: 4:48]>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:5:63
   |
4  |   let is_valid_color = |c| c < &'a' && c > &'m';
   |                        ------------------------
   |                        |
   |                        doesn't satisfy `<_ as FnOnce<(&char,)>>::Output = bool`
   |                        doesn't satisfy `_: FnMut<(&char,)>`
5  |   let invalid_colors_count = s.chars().filter(is_valid_color).count();
   |                                                               ^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Filter<Chars<'_>, [closure@src/main.rs:4:24: 4:48]>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
  ::: /home/ryokugin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/adapters/filter.rs:15:1
   |
15 | pub struct Filter<I, P> {
   | ----------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: Iterator`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<[closure@src/main.rs:4:24: 4:48] as FnOnce<(&char,)>>::Output = bool`
           which is required by `Filter<Chars<'_>, [closure@src/main.rs:4:24: 4:48]>: Iterator`
           `[closure@src/main.rs:4:24: 4:48]: FnMut<(&char,)>`
           which is required by `Filter<Chars<'_>, [closure@src/main.rs:4:24: 4:48]>: Iterator`
           `Filter<Chars<'_>, [closure@src/main.rs:4:24: 4:48]>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&mut Filter<Chars<'_>, [closure@src/main.rs:4:24: 4:48]>: Iterator`
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from @Enselic is correct, but here I'll explain why the error message is so strange.

The method `count()` exists [on the `Iterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count). That means that as long as a type implement `Iterator` it'll have `.count()`.

[`Iterator::filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) returns the [`Filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Filter.html) type. It [implements `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Filter.html#impl-Iterator)... conditionally:

```rust
impl<I: Iterator, P> Iterator for Filter<I, P>
where
    P: FnMut(&I::Item) -> bool,
```

This is desugared as (see [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound)):

```rust
impl<I: Iterator, P> Iterator for Filter<I, P>
where
    P: for<'a> FnMut(&'a I::Item) -> bool,
```

If we remove the `.count()`...

```rust
let is_invalid = |c| c == &'a';
let invalids = s.chars().filter(is_invalid);
```

...the compiler hints us:

```rust
error: implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
 --> src/main.rs:4:30
  |
4 |     let invalids = s.chars().filter(is_invalid);
  |                              ^^^^^^ implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
  |
  = note: closure with signature `fn(&'2 char) -> bool` must implement `FnOnce<(&'1 char,)>`, for any lifetime `'1`...
  = note: ...but it actually implements `FnOnce<(&'2 char,)>`, for some specific lifetime `'2`
```

So, instead of a closure that implements `for<'a> FnOnce(&'a char) -> bool`, we wrote a closure that implements `FnOnce(&'a char) -> bool` for some lifetime `'a` that the compiler inferred.

This is because Rust fails to infer HRTB (Higher-Ranked Trait Bounds, `for` clause) for closures. See e.g. [issue 50973](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50973).

Because of that, the `Filter` instance that `filter()` returns does not implement `Iterator`.

For some reason, rustc prefers to show the "traits bounds were not satisfied" error rather than the error for `filter()`, "implementation is not general enough". I don't know why it does not shows at least both.

If we hint rustc that the closure takes a reference, i.e. `|c: &_| ...` (and of course `|c: &char| ...` works too), it infers the HRTB correctly, and thus the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assist with type info as Rust can not quite figure it out by itself in this case. The following works, where the type of the closure parameter is explicit:

```rust
    let is_invalid = |c: &char| c == &'a';
    let invalids = s.chars().filter(is_invalid).count();
```

Comment: Yes, it make sense! I expect a little too much from the compiler..